# Reinit a jCarousel after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I am trying to reinitialise the jCarousel(sorgalla.com/jcarousel), after update data from server

**.js**

```
$.reloadJc = function(){
 $.get('jc.html', function(data){
  $('ul.myjc').htlm(data);
  $t.carousel.reset(); // $t.carousel is my jcarousel instance
  $t.carousel.reload();
 });
}
$.reloadJc();
```

What I want is jcarousel rebuild the list every time I call this function.

Comment: exactly which carousel plugin are you using?

Comment: jCarousel - http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Comment: Did you find an answer to your problem?

Comment: no i dont... i did a workaround

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild the jCarousel after the new dom items are added. First load the page and create jCarousel. Since you cannot reinitialise jCarousel you need to create another jCarousel . Load the dom with the new html and apply the jCarousel to the new elements.

I used jTemplate and json for this functionality. It takes some time to get things right, but if the job calls for it it can be done.